# IntelliJ IDEA Run Scala Console throwing exception

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, console

When trying to run Scala Console from IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.2.2 I get the following Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(Lscala/tools/nsc/Settings;)V
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:64)

The SCALA plugin is installed correctly and the project compiles and runs correctly within the IDE but when I try to run the Console I get an error.

Comment: The original question has only one answer that says it is a bug. That was in 2015. Does this mean the bug has been going on since 2015?

Comment: @Soldalma I have opened a the following ticket and it looks like a regression https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12450

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the images and they are exactly like what I saw when I tried to run the console within IntelliJ.

Comment: Is there a way to run scala REPL from commans line under windows if the only thing that was installed is JDK (jdk-8u144-windows-i586.exe) and IDEA Community (ideaIC-2017.2.3.exe). If someone knows full/exact command line please write it. I know that I could download and unpack standalone scala but the point is not to create even bigger mess but to hopefully arrive at a one liner workaround.

Comment: Have a look at the link in my comment. The regression is now fixed so just update intellij and the console should work

Comment: OK, they get a plus for a quick fix but just because it has been fixed doesn't mean that it's been released :-) As I thought - it only offered to update Python plugin. Anyway, I'd like to learn if that's doable (a REPL from intellij's scala files but without intellij running) in general without having to bring the 2nd "install" (OK it's just unpack but would have to go into path to be usable) and opening the doors for a latter version conflict hell.

Comment: @ZXX not sure how you updated your IED but when I updated mine with the new patch the SCALA Console worked fine. Also I suggest maybe posting a new question rather than trying to solve a new problem within a "somewhat" unrelated topic. I suggest may be a question with a title  "Is there a way to run scala REPL from command line under windows if the only thing that was installed is JDK (jdk-8u144-windows-i586.exe) and IDEA Community (ideaIC-2017.2.3.exe)"