# I Installed IntelliJ Idea with the Scala plugin. Why don't I have a scalac file anywhere?

Tags: scala, console, read-eval-print-loop

It is my second day with `Scala` and `IntelliJ Idea`. I can run a `Hello World` program. I want to enter Scala commands interactively, in a REPL. However, the console does not work. Supposedly there is a bug. So I tried to go to the `Command Prompt` and run `Scala` with `scalac.exe`. But no file `scalac.exe` or `scala.exe` exists on my hard disk (I checked). What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to launch Scala Console in IntelliJ, or install SBT and use its Scala console or install Scala with a CLI

Documentation for SBT: it's a compiler package for Scala (like Maven & co) in which you can launch a Scala console. Open a terminal and type sbt, it should be ok. You should be able to launch it in an independent console or in IntelliJ's terminal. http://www.scala-sbt.org/

This shows you how to start the Scala console you get with IntelliJ, if you only installed the Scala plugin coming with IntelliJ. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53326888

This helps you find the location of your installed Scala exe. https://scala-lang.org/download/install.html

Comment: Please let me know how it goes for you, and mark the question as answered if it fits you

Comment: I was able to download the binaries and to add paths to my environment variables. I can now execute the command `scala` in the command prompt and execute Scala commands. However, the Scala console on IntelliJ still does not work. When I hit Ctrl+Shift+D I get this message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(Lscala/tools/nsc/Settings;)V
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:64)`. There is a question on SO about this but it was marked as duplicate and the original answer does not help.

Comment: Do you have the link of the-said SO question?

Comment: Could you give me the version of Scala you have? Type scala -version

Comment: `scala -version` on the command prompt gives version 2.12.3. However, this may not be the same version in IntelliJ, which is where I am having problems with the console.

Comment: Here is the link for the SO question: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844610/intellij-idea-run-scala-console-throwing-exception>